# How to add spell check to a php function

Tags: php

I’m new to coding and I have been searching for a script to create a list of Anagrams, the following script is what I am using but it will display a list of words made up of every possible combination.

I’m wanting to add a spell check to the function such as pspell_check() which I found here visit https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-check.php

The idea is to only display words from the English dictionary.

Any help would be appreciated if anyone can show me how to add spell check to this code.

```
<?php 
// PHP program to print all  
// permutations of a given string. 


/** 
* permutation function 
* @param str string to  
*  calculate permutation for 
* @param l starting index 
* @param r end index 
*/
function permute($str, $l, $r) 
{ 
    if ($l == $r) 
        echo $str. "\n"; 
    else
    { 
        for ($i = $l; $i <= $r; $i++) 
        { 
            $str = swap($str, $l, $i); 
            permute($str, $l + 1, $r); 
            $str = swap($str, $l, $i); 
        } 
    } 
} 

/** 
* Swap Characters at position 
* @param a string value 
* @param i position 1 
* @param j position 2 
* @return swapped string 
*/
function swap($a, $i, $j) 
{ 
    $temp; 
    $charArray = str_split($a); 
    $temp = $charArray[$i] ; 
    $charArray[$i] = $charArray[$j]; 
    $charArray[$j] = $temp; 
    return implode($charArray); 
} 

// Driver Code 
$str = "ANAGRAM"; 
$n = strlen($str); 
permute($str, 0, $n - 1); 

// This code is contributed by mits. 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
// PHP program to print all  
// permutations of a given string. 


/** 
* permutation function 
* @param str string to  
*  calculate permutation for 
* @param l starting index 
* @param r end index 
*/
function permute($str, $l, $r, $pspell_link) 
{ 
    if ($l == $r) {
        if (pspell_check($pspell_link, $str)) {
            echo $str. "\n"; 
        };
    }
    else
    { 
        for ($i = $l; $i <= $r; $i++) 
        { 
            $str = swap($str, $l, $i); 
            permute($str, $l + 1, $r, $pspell_link); 
            $str = swap($str, $l, $i); 
        } 
    } 
} 

/** 
* Swap Characters at position 
* @param a string value 
* @param i position 1 
* @param j position 2 
* @return swapped string 
*/
function swap($a, $i, $j) 
{ 
    $temp; 
    $charArray = str_split($a); 
    $temp = $charArray[$i] ; 
    $charArray[$i] = $charArray[$j]; 
    $charArray[$j] = $temp; 
    return implode($charArray); 
} 

// Driver Code 
$str = "ANAGRAM"; 
$n = strlen($str);

$pspell_link = pspell_new("en"); // pspell  has to be enabled on your web server
permute($str, 0, $n - 1, $pspell_link); 

// This code is contributed by mits. 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help very kind! One query though, if there are no Anagrams of a word it just echos the original $str 5 times on the page?